# Assigning onclick to PopupWindow contents in the main activity

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, popupwindow

I am trying to implement a stream player. There is a popup layout other than the `activity_main` layout that is shown. However, if I try to click the `ImageView` inside the popup, the click event is not triggered.

Given below is my popup window layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="POPUP"
            android:textColor="#be2525"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_close_popup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="#d2f4d4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Close"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_stream_one"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_deutsches_musik_radio"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_stream_two"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_deutsches_musik_radio"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.amplitude.tron.popupwindows.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/playerControl"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@null"/>

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Click me"/>
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_create_popup"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="POPUP" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I'm handling the click actions in my popup window

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnClosePopup;
    Button btnCreatePopup;
    ImageButton playControlButton;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private PopupWindow pwindo;

    ImageView streamOne,streamTwo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        btnCreatePopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_create_popup);
        btnCreatePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();
            }
        });

        playControlButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playerControl);

        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            playControlButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
        }
        else
        {
            playControlButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_stop);
        }

        playControlButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    playControlButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
                    playStream("http://136.243.133.81:8000/live");
                }
                else
                {
                    playControlButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void playStream(String url)
    {
         mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                playControlButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playerControl);
                playControlButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_stop);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

    //POPUP WINDOW
    private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int w = dm.widthPixels;
        int h = dm.heightPixels;
        int newWidth = w-50;
        int newHeight=h-300;

        try {
            // We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout,newWidth, newHeight, true);

            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            pwindo.setFocusable(true);


            btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

            streamOne = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_stream_two);
            streamOne.setOnClickListener(availableStreams);
            streamOne = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_stream_two);
            streamTwo.setOnClickListener(availableStreams);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pwindo.dismiss();
        }
    };


    private View.OnClickListener availableStreams = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button_stream_one:
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    playStream("http://136.243.133.81:8000/live");
                    break;
                case R.id.button_stream_two:
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    playStream("http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/top-40.aac");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The imageview was not getting initialised due OOM exception.The error was not shown in the Logcat, however at design level of the app i got a exception alert so after opening the details i got the below OOM.
at android.widget.ImageView.

So for this i added the following to the Manifest:

- `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`
- `android:largeHeap="true"`

possible work around for images that cause OOM exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough I believe PopupWindow is not focusable by default.

```
pwindo.setFocusable(true);
```

should allow your button to work

Comment: nothing happened with the above solution, the debugger never enters the onclick event :|

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the `onClick` action for your `button_stream_one` and `button_stream_two`.

```
// Declare these private variables
private ImageView btnStreamOne;
private ImageView btnStreamTwo;
```

And then in your popup initialization function.

```
btnStreamOne = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_stream_one);
btnStreamOne.setOnClickListener(streamOneClick);

btnStreamTwo = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_stream_two);
btnStreamTwo.setOnClickListener(streamTwoClick);
```

And you need to set the `ImageView` clickable in the layout.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button_stream_one"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_deutsches_musik_radio"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button_stream_two"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_deutsches_musik_radio"/>
```

**Update**

Try writing two different `onClickListener` for those two `ImageView`.

```
private View.OnClickListener streamOneClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        playStream("http://136.243.133.81:8000/live");        
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener streamTwoClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        playStream("http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/top-40.aac");        
    }
};
```

**Update 2**

I cloned your project and found you're referencing the wrong view for the `ImageView`. I couldn't push the code changes to your Github repository as I don't have the permission. But anyway, I'm pasting the changed part here. Try replacing the following functions in your code.

```
//POPUP WINDOW
private void initiatePopupWindow() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int w = dm.widthPixels;
    int h = dm.heightPixels;
    int newWidth = w - 50;
    int newHeight = h - 300;

    try {
        // We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, newWidth, newHeight, true);

        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        pwindo.setFocusable(true);

        btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
        btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

        streamOne = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_stream_one);
        streamOne.setOnClickListener(streamOneClick);
        streamTwo = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_stream_two);
        streamTwo.setOnClickListener(streamTwoClick);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private View.OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pwindo.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener streamOneClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        playStream("http://136.243.133.81:8000/live");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stream one button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pwindo.dismiss();
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener streamTwoClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        playStream("http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/top-40.aac");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stream two button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pwindo.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Comment: same result nothing happened, actually i had initialized the imageView like you have suggested, but i undid my code that's why it dint end up in the code i attached in the question above. I have updated the above code anyways!

Comment: Did you make them clickable too?

Comment: Yeah thats what amuses me close button works but not imageView :D

Comment: You tried with writing two different `onClickListener` like the updated answer too? If it doesn't work too, please add a toast onClick on the close button to see if the close button in actually clicked or not.

Comment: i have added the above to git incase you have doubts you can check the [repo](https://github.com/Quantron7t/PopupWindows)

Comment: Hi, see the updated answer. I've cloned your repo and tried fixing your code. It works now.